# error in build a package

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i has a package in my home named navibot , it's CMake is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)

rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

rosbuild_add_executable(navibot src/navibot_v1.1New.cpp)
  
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

**when building it i get 1 failure :**

---

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['navibot']                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/salma/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130320-070702
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['navibot'] to:
['navibot']                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> navibot [ make ]                                       
[ rosmake ] All 38 linesavibot: 5.1 sec ]            [ 1 Active 14/15 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package navibot
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/client_rosjava_jni/rosjava_jni/cmake/rosjava.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/salma/navibot/build
  cd build && make -l1
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/navibot.dir/src/navibot_v1.1New.o
  /home/salma/navibot/src/navibot_v1.1New.cpp:13:119: fatal error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/msg_gen/cpp/include/turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/navibot.dir/src/navibot_v1.1New.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/navibot.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/salma/navibot/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package navibot written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/salma/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130320-070702/navibot/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< navibot [FAIL] [ 5.17 seconds ]                        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package navibot. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 15 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/salma/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130320-070702
```

**I tried to add in cmake file

> **rosbuild_add_boost_directories()**

and

> **rosbuild_link_boost(navibot thread)**

but the same fail happened again
where is the wrong ??**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58658/error-in-build-a-package/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't look like your error is related to boost, but rather to a failure to find the TurtlebotSensorState message.  See this part of your build log:

```
/home/salma/navibot/src/navibot_v1.1New.cpp:13:119: fatal error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/msg_gen/cpp/include/turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Check to make sure that you have the turtlebot stack installed, and that it's listed in the dependency list for your package.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) on 2014-11-25**:
How I can install turtlebot stack? I echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, result is:
/home/mai/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/**stacks**